# Get current row in from sumif statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I'm using Excel 2010 and have a datasheet with multiple tabs, this is the current `SUMIF` function that I am using

```
 =IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$J$2:$J$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,Current_row_different column, "")
```

Basically, I find some rows in the other sheet that have a value of 1 I then want to use these rows that have a value of 1 but use a different column within that row to populate the true condition.

So say for instance row 4 contains a 1 at column A I then want to stay on row 4 but get the value of column B for the true condition.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I have now managed to get the function working however its a bit of an Excel hack, because I have had to move the columns around in the master data and its a bit messy now anyway here's what I've got

```
 =IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,VLOOKUP(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$F$90,3,FALSE),"")
```

Now I know this is because `VLOOKUP` searches through the first column specified and it doesn't seem to work at all if i try to put the range in backwards i.e. $F$90:$C$2 instead of $C$2:$F$90. Is there any way to manipulate VLOOKUP to work like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually there is a way - a brother of `VLOOKUP` - it's `INDEX(MATCH())`. It is a very useful tool, as you can look at any column and return any other, not only looking at the first one to return the ones to the right. Also, `INDEX(MATCH())` can be used in forming array formulas, if you need that, while `VLOOKUP` cannot.

Basically, this part of your formula:

`VLOOKUP(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$F$90,3,FALSE)`

would be changed with this:

`INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$90,MATCH(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$90,FALSE))`

So, after all, the equivalent for

```
=IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,VLOOKUP(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$F$90,3,FALSE),"")
```

would be

```
=IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$90,MATCH(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$90,FALSE)),"")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks very much for your help sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Have done as requested there. I'm just having one more small problem now in that when I use 
     =IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$90,MATCH(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$90,FALSE)),"")

C is a persons name in a pivot table and sometimes there is multiple instances of this name and then the index only returns the first result found. I have a flag set to 1 in column W when its the row I want is there anyway to only match with the rows where column W =1 or >1 as specified in the sumif

Sorry if this is very confusing

Comment: Could you please create another well formulated and formatted question for that? It's difficult to explain it here in comments section, but I think I understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Probably should have done that to begin with here is the link to the new question thanks again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29259140/excel-index-only-retrieve-certain-rows-under-a-criteria