# INDEX to retrieve only certain rows under a criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had a problem, now fixed, that can be seen here: [Excel Get current row in from sumif statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29213421/excel-get-current-row-in-from-sumif-statement#comment46673731_29222235). I'm just having one more small problem now in that when I use:

```
=IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$90,MATCH(B22,'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$90,FALSE)),"")
```

C is a persons name in a table and sometimes there is multiple instances of this name and then when searching the index only returns the first result found. I have a flag set to `1` in column W when its the row I want.

Is there any way to only match with the rows where column W =1 or >1 as specified in the SUMIF?

I can fix the problem if I sort the original table by the flag largest first but that's a bit of a hack. What I'm looking for would be something like this:

```
=IF(SUMIF('Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200,'Resource View (2)'!B22,'Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200)>0,INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$90,MATCH(B22**WHERE'Master Data!$W2:$W$200>0**,'Master Data'!$C$2:$C$90,FALSE)),"")
```

Or if there is a way to create a second instance of the table I have, that only shows results that have the flag >0?

I can just copy the table and put it in a hidden sheet but in that case any new entries to the original table won't be added to the table in the hidden sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should do it:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$200,MATCH(1,(B22='Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200)*('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200=1),FALSE)),"")
```

But you will need to enter it array formula. Not using <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but instead - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Genius! Thanks a million! Just what I needed and from quite a confusing explanation bravo sir!

Comment: This is not necessary but would be a help if possible, The flag W basically means assigned, I have another flag X which means part assigned is there any way to check for both something like this would be perfect but i cant get the syntax right `=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$200,OR(MATCH(1,(B22='Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200)*('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200=1),(MATCH(1,(B22='Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200)*('Master Data'!$X$2:$X$200=1),FALSE))),"")`

Comment: EDIT thought I had it with `=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$200,MATCH(1,(B22='Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200)*OR('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200=1),('Master Data'!$X$2:$X$200=1)),FALSE)),"")` but strange results seem to show when I use that ?

Comment: `=IFERROR(INDEX('Master Data'!$E$2:$E$200,MATCH(1,(B22='Master Data'!$C$2:$C$200)*('Master Data'!$W$2:$W$200=1)*('Master Data'!$X$2:$X$200=1),FALSE)),"")`

Comment: Tried that as well no luck unfortunately ended up creating two tables one for assigned and one for part assigned